# Input TextArea and Output TextArea and Save To

Tags: html, text, vbscript, hta

I've written up a quick hta for quick actions via button: copy to clipboard, message boxes, and run specific files. Now I'm trying figure out how to add:

2 textarea boxes

1. TextArea1 - Type text inside
2. Submit button to save textarea1 to local file and load to textarea2
3. TextArea2 - will display text from saved local file from textarea1

Thanks for your time and consideration

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>**All Access QL v1.0**</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION 
    ID="TestHTA" 
    APPLICATIONNAME="TestHTA"
    ICON = "C:\L.S.L._QL_HTAv1.0\Media\RazerIcon.ico"
    BORDER="thin"
    MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
    MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
    SCROLL="no"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="no"
    SysMenu="no"
    WINDOWSTATE="normal">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="all" type="text/css"/>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
    Sub Window_onLoad
        window.resizeTo 510,510
    End Sub


    Sub ExitProgram
        window.close()
    End Sub


    Sub fileupdate
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        objFSO.CopyFolder "C:\CopyFromLocation1","C:\CopyToLocation1", True
    End Sub



    Sub lotsiu
        strMessage = "Line 1" & vbNewLine & "Line 2"

        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

        With objWord
        .Visible = False
        .Documents.Add
        .Selection.TypeText strMessage
        .Selection.WholeStory
        .Selection.Copy
        .Quit False
        End With
    End Sub


    Sub faqmbrPhonumuse
        msgbox "Line 1" & vbNewLine & "Line 2"
    End Sub


    Sub appword 
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        objShell.Run "WINWORD.exe"
    End Sub



    sub Window_onLoad()
        set oFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        set oFile=oFSO.OpenTextFile("Test.txt",1)
        text=oFile.ReadAll
        document.all.ScriptArea.value=text
        oFile.Close
    End sub

    Sub Submitarea
        Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile( "TextArea.txt",8,true)
        sTxtarea = document.all("Txtarea").Value
        oFIle.Write sTxtarea & vbCRLF
        MsgBox "Your text has been added to TextArea.txt", 64,"Textarea Input"
        oFile.close
    End Sub 'Submitarea


</SCRIPT>

    </head>

<body>

<div id="Title">
    <b>PSC Quick Access</b> 
    <input id="checkButton" class="upbutton" type="button" value="UPDATE" name="run_button" onClick="fileupdate" align="right">
    <input id="checkButton" class="upbutton" type="button" value="EXIT" name="run_button" onClick="ExitProgram" align="right">
</div>

<div id="SubTitle">
    Email- Phone Number
</div>

<div id="Icon">

</div>
<br>
<div id="ContentBox">
    <b>Fax Temps (Click and Paste)</b>
</div>
<input id="checkButton" class="faxbutton" type="button" value="Button 1" name="btn_Next" onClick="button1" align="right">
<br>
<div id="ContentBox">
    <b>Apps (Click To Start)</b>
</div>
<input id="checkButton" class="appbutton" type="button" value="Notepad" name="run_button" onclick="appnotepad" align="right">
<input id="checkButton" class="appbutton" type="button" value="Word" name="run_button" onClick="appword" align="right">
<br>
<div id="ContentBox">
    <b>FAQs (Click for Info)</b>
</div>
<input id="checkButton" class="faqbutton" type="button" value="Num For Mbr" name="run_button" onClick="faqmbrPhonumuse" align="right">
<br>
<div id="ContentBox">
    <b>Lotus Temps (Click and Paste)</b>
</div>
<input id="checkButton" class="lotbutton" type="button" value="SIU" name="btn_Next" onClick="lotsiu" align="right">
</div>
    <form method="POST">
    <TEXTAREA style="
    Height:193;
    Width:100%;
    font-Size:12;
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#ffffe7;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:MS Sans Serif" 
    TITLE=""
    NAME=Txtarea TABORDER=2 WRAP=PHYSICAL>The contents of this text area will be written to C:\TextArea.doc when you click submit.******First time submit is click if file has not been created it will be create automatically daily log with system date appended at the end******and will append data to top of file with prefix of system time******Line at end of margin will have hard return when text is at the end******And get and display new changed text in the lower text box and diplayed******Lower textarea has scroll and can be highlighted, but not editable"</TEXTAREA>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Submitarea">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear">
    <br><br>
    <textarea name="ScriptArea" rows=10 cols=70></textarea><p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should post what did you do so far !

Comment: Thank you for looking into what I've got so far, due to the sensitivity of the data I stripped out the specific functions, but left the skeleton of what I have so far. The textarea function is one of the last few components I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT : 09/03/2015** Try something like that :

```
<html>
<Title>How to open and read the log file with HTA</Title>
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
ICON="cmd.exe"
APPLICATIONNAME = "How to open and read the log file with HTA" 
BORDER="dialog"
BORDERSTYLE="complex"
WINDOWSTATE="maximize"
>
<style>
body{
background-color: Black;
}
</style>
</head>
<script type="text/Vbscript">
Option Explicit
Dim File,fso,oFile,objShell
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
File = "C:\Test_" _
    & Month(Date) & "_" & Day(Date) & "_" & Year(Date) _
    & ".txt"
'***********************************************************
Sub LoadMyFile()
    txtBody.Value = LoadFile(File)
End Sub
'***********************************************************
Function LoadFile(File)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim fso,F,ReadMe,strError
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set F = fso.OpenTextFile(File,1)
    If Err.Number <> 0  Then
        strError = "<center><b><font color=Red>The file "& File &" dosen't exists !</font></b></center>"
        myDiv.InnerHTML = strError
        Exit Function
    End If
    ReadMe = F.ReadAll
    LoadFile = ReadMe
End Function
'***********************************************************
Sub Clear()
    txtBody.Value = ""
    myDiv.InnerHTML = ""
    Txtarea.Value = ""
End Sub
'***********************************************************
Function LogOpen()
    Dim Ws,iReturn,strError
    Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    On Error Resume Next
    iReturn = Ws.Run(File,1,False)
    If Err.Number <> 0  Then
        strError = "<center><b><font color=Red>The file "& File &" dosen't exists !</font></b></center>"
        myDiv.InnerHTML = strError
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
'***********************************************************
Sub Submitarea()
    Dim oFile,sTxtarea,Readfile,ReadAllTextFile,strError
    If Not fso.FileExists(File) Then
        Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile(File,2,true)
        oFIle.write "The File "& File &" is created at " & FormatDateTime(now,vbLongTime)
        oFile.Close
    End If
    Set Readfile = fso.OpenTextFile(File,1)
    ReadAllTextFile = Readfile.ReadAll
    Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile(File,2,true)
    sTxtarea = document.all("Txtarea").Value
    oFIle.Writeline
    oFIle.write ("Name ")
    oFIle.write FormatDateTime(now, 2)
    oFIle.write (" ")
    oFIle.write FormatDateTime(now,vbLongTime)
    'FormatDateTime(now, 4)
    oFIle.write (" - ")
    oFIle.Write sTxtarea & vbCrLf
    oFIle.WriteLine ReadAllTextFile
    myDiv.InnerHTML = "Your text has been added to "& File &""
    oFile.Close
    Call LoadMyFile()
End Sub
'***********************************************************
</script>
<body text="white">
<center><input type="button" name="Log" id="Start" value="  Load LogFile  " onclick="LoadMyFile()"><br><br>
<textarea id="txtBody" rows="15" cols="120"></textarea><br><br>
<input type="button" name="Log" id="Start" value="  Open LogFile with Notepad  " onclick="LogOpen()">
<input type="button" value="  Clear  " onclick="Clear()"></center>
<Div id="myDiv"></Div>
<br><br>
<TEXTAREA style="
Height:193;
Width:100%;
font-Size:12;
color:#000000;
background-color:#ffffe7;
font-weight:normal;
font-family:MS Sans Serif" 
TITLE="" 
ID="Txtarea" NAME="Txtarea" TABORDER="2" WRAP="PHYSICAL">The contents of this text area will be written to TextArea.txt when you click submit.</TEXTAREA><br><br>
<center><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Submitarea">
<input type="reset" value="Reset"></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll add it in tonight after work.

This is what I had in mind for the naming of log file, would this work too.

set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set file = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Experimental\Daily_Call_Log_.txt", ForAppending, CreateIfNeeded)
Set File = fso.OpenTextFile( _
        "C:\Experimental\Daily_Call_Log_" _
        & Month(Date) & "_" & Day(Date) & "_" & Year(Date) _
        & ".txt", ForAppending, CreateIfNeeded)

Comment: So I tried it ou, but once I lug it into my .HTA it fails to work properly. Seems like when I add text into the script language it throws everything else off.

Comment: Alright tried out today and my last step in that is text that is in textarea when submit is clicked the text is appended to top of text file. ergo
Line 1 - Name 3/8/2015 14:51
Line 2 - Name 3/8/2015 14:47
Line 3 - Name 3/8/2015 14:43
Line 4 - Name 3/8/2015 14:39
Line 5 - Name 3/8/2015 14:30

Comment: Awesome thank you. I will try it out at the office tomorrow. You have been so helpful and I've been learning so much about how textarea works by analyzing your work. To give a little insight on how much, I've just started learning from examples just over 12 days ago. Till then I have never coded anything.

Comment: Ran the hta through the hoops today and it worked great. I modified the textarea size smaller to accommodate my specified window size.  I need to leave notes in a 3rd party system and this current setup works great, but I was wondering if there is any way to insert a hard/carriage return every time a new line is required when text hits the right margin?