# VBScript: Cannot display log file in .HTA

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am having trouble displaying a log file in the TextArea of a HTA while a robocopy script is running.

The script is simple enough, the user has one button to press to start the process, selects where they want to back up their data to, a Robocopy runs in the background and logs the work.

I cannot get the .log file to display live during the process and am always hit with an error 800A01B6.

Code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Backup Script</title>

<HTA:APPLICATION
 ID="Backup Script"
 APPLICATIONNAME="Backup Script"
 BORDER="thin"
 SCROLL="no"
 SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
 WINDOWSTATE="normal"
>
</head>

<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">

Sub Window_OnLoad
  intWidth = 800
  intHeight = 800
  Me.ResizeTo intWidth, intHeight
  Me.MoveTo ((Screen.Width / 2) - (intWidth / 2)),((Screen.Height / 2) - (intHeight / 2))
End Sub

Sub run_Backup_Script

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Dim NetSharedFolder, TargetLocalFolder, Settings


'Delete Log File bigger than 10MB
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If oFSO.FileExists("D:\Public\Backup.log") Then
Set file = oFSO.GetFile("D:\Public\Backup.log")
if file.Size >= 10485760 Then
oFSO.DeleteFile("D:\Public\Backup.log")
  End If
End If

'Set Settings
Settings = " /MIR /FFT /R:3 /LOG+:D:\Public\Backup.log"
NetSharedFolder = "D:\LocalData\" & WshNetwork.UserName

'Select Target Folder
TargetLocalFolder = BrowseFolder( "Desktop", True , "Select a destination folder")

'Backup starts
objExecute = "RoboCopy.exe " & chr(34) & NetSharedFolder & chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & TargetLocalFolder & chr(34) & " " & Settings & chr(34)
WshShell.Run objExecute, 0, True
DisplayOutput "D:\Public\Backup.log"

End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sub DisplayOutput(strFileName)
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, 1, False)
BasicTextArea.Text = BasicTextArea.Text & VbCrLf & objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------------------

Function BrowseFolder( myStartLocation, blnSimpleDialog, myMessage )
Const MY_COMPUTER = &H11&
Const WINDOW_HANDLE = 0 ' Must ALWAYS be 0

Dim numOptions, objFolder, objFolderItem
Dim objPath, objShell, strPath, strPrompt

' Set the options for the dialog window
strPrompt = myMessage
If blnSimpleDialog = True Then
numOptions = 0 ' Simple dialog
Else
numOptions = &H10& ' Additional text field to type folder path
End If

' Create a Windows Shell object
Set objShell = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )

' If specified, convert "My Computer" to a valid
' path for the Windows Shell's BrowseFolder method
If UCase( myStartLocation ) = "MY COMPUTER" Then
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace( MY_COMPUTER )
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
strPath = objFolderItem.Path
Else
strPath = myStartLocation
End If

Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder( WINDOW_HANDLE, strPrompt, _
numOptions, strPath )

' Quit if no folder was selected
If objFolder Is Nothing Then
BrowseFolder = ""
Exit Function
End If

' Retrieve the path of the selected folder
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
objPath = objFolderItem.Path

' Return the path of the selected folder
BrowseFolder = objPath
End Function

</SCRIPT>

'------------------------------------------------------------------------

<body STYLE="font:14 pt arial;     color:white;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient
(GradientType=1, StartColorStr='#000033', EndColorStr='#0000FF')"     onkeypress='vbs:Default_Buttons'>
<table width='90%' height = '50%' align='center' border='0'>
<tr>
<td align='center' colspan="4">
<h3>Backup Script</h3><br>
</td>
</tr
<tr>
<td align='center' colspan="2">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>
<input id="bt_Backup" type="button"  value="Run Now" name="Run Now" onClick="vbs:run_Backup_Script">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>


</br></br>
<textarea id="BasicTextArea" name="BasicTextArea" rows="5" cols="75"></textarea>


</html>
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Error 800A01B6 means "object doesn't support this property or method". Which statement is raising the error?

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801959/input-textarea-and-output-textarea-and-save-to/28877149#28877149