# HTA: Show text file in a scrollable popup window

Tags: popup, text-files, hta

I'm looking for a minimalistic way to view the contents of my text (.txt) file.
I can call the file with notepad, but I don't want a user to be able to directly edit the file.

Is it possible to show the content in a scrollable popup window? Preferably without the use of javascript.

Comment: In an iframe with `src` pointing to the textfile? Or a link with `href` pointing to the textfile, and with `target="_blank"` attribute.

Comment: Done this before by building an `iframe` that loads a HTML page that reads the text file from a `ADODB.Stream` and outputs it to a `pre` HTML tag. You could even do it without the iframe just load the txt file using the `ADODB.Stream` and output it to a fixed height with overflow set.

Comment: Take a look at this answer [How to open and read the log file with HTA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801959/input-textarea-and-output-textarea-and-save-to?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: You put me on the right track @Teemu, thanks.

Comment: Your hta looks sweet @Hackoo, but a bit to complex for my need. Thanks for the headsup though

Answer (score 3):

I created a new sub .hta which I call from my main .hta
Works great except when I convert the sub .hta to a .exe with HTAEdit, it won't open my log file :/ Well that's another issue to solve :)

Here's my sub .hta code:

```
<head>
<title>Log File Viewer</title>

<HTA:APPLICATION
  INNERBORDER="no"
  SYSMENU="yes"
  MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  SCROLL="no"
  SCROLLFLAT="yes"
  SHOWINTASKBAR="no"
  CONTEXTMENU="no"
  SELECTION="no"/>
</head>
<script language="Javascript">

        window.resizeTo(600,450); // Width,Height
        window.moveTo(window.screen.width/3,window.screen.height/3);

</script>
<script language="VBScript">
Dim strHTML

Sub Window_OnLoad
    logfile = "LOG_" & DatePart("yyyy",Date) & "_" & Right("0" & DatePart("m",Date), 2) & ".txt"
    strHTML = ""
    strHTML = strHTML & "<div id='list'>"
    strHTML = strHTML & "<p><iframe src='logs\" & logfile & "' frameborder='0' height='330' width='100%'></iframe></p>"
    strHTML = strHTML & "</div>"
    LogViewer.InnerHTML = strHTML
End Sub

Sub ClosePopup
    window.close
End Sub

</script>


<body>

<div id="LogViewer"></div>
<center><input type="button" id="Close" value="Close Log Viewer" onclick="VBScript:ClosePopup"></center>

</body>

</html>
```